# Scrapy - ItemPipeline does not enter Process Items

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I'm playing around with Scrapy, and trying to pass items generated by Spiders to an ItemPipe. THe issue is, while the pipe is entered, the actual process_items method is never called. That despite having debugged the spider and seeing that it's correctly yielding Quote items. To summarise, when I debug quotes_spider.py I can see the 'item' object I return is of type Quote, with author/quote having expected values. Similarly, the pipe is loaded correctly and the json file is created, I simply never enter the process_items method or write to such file. Any advice?

quotes_spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from tutorial.item_loaders import QuoteLoader
from tutorial.items import Quote


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "quote")]'):
            l = QuoteLoader(item=Quote(), response=response)
            content = quote.xpath('./span[contains(@itemprop, "text")]/text()').extract_first()
            l.add_value('quote', content)
            author = quote.xpath('./span/small[contains(@itemprop, "author")]/text()').extract_first()
            l.add_value('author', author)

            item = l.load_item()

            yield item
```

Items.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class TutorialItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass

class Quote(scrapy.Item):
    quote = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
```

item_loaders.py

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join


class QuoteLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

pipelines.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import json


class QuotePipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('itemss.json', 'w')
        pass

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_items(self, item, spider):
        print "HELLO"
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return "HELLO"
```

In settings.py I have correctly defined:

```
# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'tutorial.pipelines.QuotePipeline': 300,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
process_item(self, item, spider)  #item Not items
```